# Call 'PostFiles' endpoint with FormData from Node.js application instead of website

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, multipartform-data

I have an endpoint to which files are being sent from a website - via an `<input>` field. The Angular code looks like this...

```
@Injectable()
export class FileUploadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  uploadFiles(files: any): Promise<void> {
   return new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {
       var formData = new FormData();
       for (let file of files)
           formData.append(file.name, file);

      const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `localhost:4200/api/postfiles`, formData, {
        reportProgress: true,
      });

    this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
      {
        console.log(`Progress: ${Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total)}`);
      }
      else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response)
        console.log(`Done`);
        resolve();
  });
});
}
}
```

...and the C# endoint like this...

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(2147483640)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            IFormFileCollection files = Request.Form.Files;
            if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No files received");
            }

            var blobs = new List<FileBlob>();
            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                //formFile.
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    var stream = new MemoryStream();
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    blobs.Add(new FileBlob(formFile.FileName, stream));
                }
            }

            if (await _blobStorage.SaveFilesAsync(blobs, "relativeTestPath"))
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            return BadRequest("Files could not be stored");
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception generated when uploading file - " + exp.Message);
            string message = $"file / upload failed!";
            return BadRequest(message);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to call the same endpoint from a Node.js application, which reads files through the

```
 fs.readFileSync()
```

method, but I have no idea about how to prepare the file content and POST it to the same 'PostFiles' endpoint.

Any idea?

Comment: If you're wondering - I'm writing an Extension for Adobe Illustrator. It consists of an Angular frontend, but I also have access to the local filesystem through Node.js, which Adobe makes available. So the extension sends files to the .NET backend, without needing an <input> control in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution (in short words) was to create an endpoint for this, and forget about FormData:

```
filecontent = fs.readFileSync(filepath, {encoding: 'base64'));
```

POST the filecontent in the body (just forget about FormData). In the backend:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFiles([FromBody] string fileContent) 
{
  var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileContent);
  var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
  //save it anywhere
}
```